# In a GitHub Action, how do I override a service's entrypoint?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I need to define a service in my GitHub action and override its entrypoint by adding arguments to it. How can I do this?

Here's a docker-compose that works that I'm trying to translate.

```
version: '2'
services:
  config:
    build: .
    links:
      - etcd

  etcd:
    image: microbox/etcd:2.1.1
    entrypoint: "etcd --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379"
    hostname: etcd
    container_name: build_etcd
    expose:
        - 2379
```

Here's my Action and how I initially thought it'd work...

```
name: Node CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    services:
      etcd:
        image: microbox/etcd:2.1.1
        options: --entrypoint 'etcd --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379'

    steps:
      ...
```

However, this blows up when initializing containers because the command it runs isn't right...

```
/usr/bin/docker create --name 1062a703242743a29bbcfda9fc19c823_microboxetcd211_3767cc --label 488dfb --network github_network_244f1c7676b8488e99c66694d06a21f2 --network-alias etcd --entrypoint 'etcd --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379' -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true microbox/etcd:2.1.1
```

The error is `unknown flag: --listen-client-urls`

I think it should actually be like this...

```
/usr/bin/docker create --name 1062a703242743a29bbcfda9fc19c823_microboxetcd211_3767cc --label 488dfb --network github_network_244f1c7676b8488e99c66694d06a21f2 --network-alias etcd --entrypoint etcd -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true microbox/etcd:2.1.1 --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379
```

Any ideas how within a GitHub Action Service definition I can override the entrypoint with arguments being passed to the executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's not possible.

The simplest thing to do is to run the docker create command with the entrypoint override and it's args as a build step. Something like this:

```
name: Node CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      ...
      - run: docker create --name build_etcd --network-alias etcd --entrypoint etcd microbox/etcd:2.1.1 --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:237
      ...
```

However, what I wound up doing is to just build and run the docker-compose.yml that I already knew worked as a step in the workflow. Here's the docker-compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  config:
    build: .
    links:
      - etcd

  etcd:
    image: microbox/etcd:2.1.1
    entrypoint: "etcd --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379"
    hostname: etcd
    container_name: build_etcd
    expose:
        - 2379
```

And here are the related steps:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build
      run: docker-compose build --pull --force-rm config
    - name: Test
      run: docker-compose run --rm config test
    ...
```