# GitHub Actions ignores/overrides Docker container's entrypoint

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I'm trying to port a GitLab Pipeline to GitHub Actions, where we use Docker containers to provide the runtime environment. In GitLab, we simply use a line `image: $DOCKER_TAG`. The images are built by ourselves, which use a script as the entry point `ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]`. The script sets up environment (e.g., by sourcing the `setvars.sh` script for the Intel compilers and calling `ulimit -s unlimited`, etc.) and calls `exec "$@"` at the end. For GitHub, I am using

```
container:
  image: ${{ matrix.DOCKER_TAG }}
```

However, the commands to be run later cannot find the needed binaries. Looking at the log, it appears that the container was created with `--entrypoint "tail"`, causing the `run.sh` script to be ignored. I tried adding `options: --entrypoint '/run.sh'` in the Workflow YAML file, but it did not get reflected in how the container was created and the command still failed.

I may be missing something obvious, though I checked both the documentation and Google. Is there any way to use the entrypoint provided by the image without creating a Docker container action?

**UPDATE** Two more things I tried:

1. Specifying the `/run.sh` script as [Custom shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#custom-shell): `shell: '/run.sh {0}'`, but got an error

```
Error: Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name. (Parameter 'expression')
```

2. Using [Docker container action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action) or [specifying a Docker image to use for a job step](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-docker-hub-action). But in both cases the Docker image has to be hard coded (or built fresh every time). Trying to use input arguments like

```
# Docker container action
image: docker://${{ inputs.docker_tag }}
```

or

```
# Job step
- uses: docker://${{ matrix.DOCKER_TAG }}
  with:
    args: ./.github/actions/build/build.sh
```

will both get an error

```
Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.docker_tag
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a GitHub Action, how do I override a service's entrypoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868127/in-a-github-action-how-do-i-override-a-services-entrypoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled along the lines below. Not ideal/DRY, as the `run.sh` entrypoint script has to be duplicated from the Docker container and kept up to date. Also, the [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) GitHub Actions does not preserve executable bits, so have to zip everything in a tar file.

```
jobs:
  build:
    container:
      image: XX/compiler:${{ matrix.DOCKER_TAG }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: ./.github/scripts/run.sh ./.github/scripts/build.sh
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build-artifact
          path: 'build-*.tar.bz2'
          retention-days: 7
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        DOCKER_TAG: [gcc, nvhpc, intel]
        include:
          - DOCKER_TAG: gcc
            FC: gfortran
          - DOCKER_TAG: nvhpc
            FC: nvfortran
          - DOCKER_TAG: intel
            FC: ifort
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a image to a job, it will execute the `steps` defined in your job inside this container. Your container image only provides the environment in which your steps will be executed. You lose control of the entrypoint and arguments.

If you only want to run your container as a single step you could do something like this instead:

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: docker://myimage:latest
```

or if you want to overwrite it:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: docker://myimage:latest
        with:
          entrypoint: /run.sh
          args: --help
```

Comment: I do want to run a sequence of commands within the container and the same container is used in different steps for different sets of commands so it's not proper to hard code what I want to do into the `run.sh` script. Is there a way to achieve similar behavior as GitLab CI?